# Django Displaying images uploaded by ImageField properly

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm building my own porfolio using Django, and I just had a question regarding uploading images using the ImageField.

I uploaded an image through the admin page using ImageField, and after a long search session, finally got my page to display the image successfully.

`urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('pages.urls')), # main landing page
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('project/',include("projects.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`projects.html`

```html
<img src="{{project.image.url}}">
```

However, the official django docs say that this is not a good way to deploy a django site. Why is that, and what is the best/proper way to display images?

Comment: Important detail for anyone who missed it - static needs to be added to the `urls.py` for your project/site, not the app. None of the documentation I saw mentioned that, but now that I'm aware of it, I can clearly see that your `urls.py` file here is listing apps (`admin` and `project`) not your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is also given in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.

Proper way of deploying media files in production is to use a reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache, or you can use a S3 compatible storage(like Amazon S3) to serve those media files as well. I can give you an example configuration in NGINX for serving media files:

```
location /media {
    alias /path/to/media/direcoty; # Change to your own media directory here.
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There are too many things to learn D: I'll take a look at using a reverse proxy server to properly deploy media files.